# Django how to read a file in the app subdirectories folder?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django to build a Web application, and there is python module inside the app folder. This python module needs to interact with yaml in the subdirectories "input" and "output".

```
map_local_path = "./input/map.yaml"
```

I just tried to read this path, it will work at my local spyder ide, but it wont work when it comes to Django.

I want to call my own python module api in views.py, and what I am doing is to:

```
openFile = open("./input/map.yaml", "r")
```

and I cannot make it work at Django.

How can I fix it? T_T Thanks!

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './input/map.yaml'

Comment: Well it looks like there is no such file. Note that the path is *relative* to the place where you call `manage.py`.

Comment: Exactly, so if you are using this code in your views or models, the path probably needs to be something like `'./name-of-your-app/input/map.yaml'`

Comment: Thank you! I see!!! './name-of-your-app/input/map.yaml' works!